# VBScript not Reading Next Line

Tags: vbscript

I have pieced together a script that is working, but not 100%.
I am reading values from a file (A) and then searching in a specific position in another file (B) for a match, then writing the entire row of data to a new file (C).
The script below works great on reading the first row in the data (file A), but it won't get past the first row.

Here is a sample list of strings I am searching for from file (A).

```
9899008KT2018012600000444
9899008KT2018012600000445
```

Here is my script:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\JeffTestFolder\9899008KT2018012600.txt", 1)
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\TestFolder\9899008KT2018012600_Compiled.txt", 8, True)
Set listFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\TestFolder\ListOfIDs.txt", 1) 
Do Until listFile.AtEndOfStream
  fName = listFile.ReadLine
  Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
    line = inFile.ReadLine
    If Mid(line, 7, 25) = fName Then outFile.WriteLine line
  Loop
Loop
```

I am stuck on how to get it to Loop and read the next line in file (A) then go search for that value in file (B) and write it to the new file (C).

Comment: It won't get past the first row because the second loop inside the first loop will read the inFile fully when the pointer is at first row of listFile

Comment: I need to read inFile fully due to their being multiple lines that will match the fName value. Those multiple matches will be written to the outFile (file C). Then I need to go back to listFile and find the next row. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Open the inFile inside listFile loop (move 2nd line of code to 7th line)

Comment: Thank you very much. I added to it to open multiple files to perform this search and it works great. I am going to get the immediate job done with it and then start adding some error checking and efficiency to the script. Might be back for pointers on doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare each line of A against each line of B you need to repeat reading B for each line of A:

```vb
Do Until listFile.AtEndOfStream
  fName = listFile.ReadLine
  Set inFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\JeffTestFolder\9899008KT2018012600.txt")
  Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
    line = inFile.ReadLine
    If Mid(line, 7, 25) = fName Then outFile.WriteLine line
  Loop
  inFile.Close
Loop
```

or read the entire file into an array or dictionary and use that array/dictionary as the reference:

```vb
txt = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\JeffTestFolder\9899008KT2018012600.txt").ReadAll
arr = Split(txt, vbNewLine)
Do Until listFile.AtEndOfStream
  fName = listFile.ReadLine
  For Each line In arr
    If Mid(line, 7, 25) = fName Then outFile.WriteLine line
  Next
Loop
```

```vb
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
txt = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\JeffTestFolder\9899008KT2018012600.txt").ReadAll
For Each line In Split(txt, vbNewLine)
  dict(Mid(line, 7, 25)) = True
Next
Do Until listFile.AtEndOfStream
  fName = listFile.ReadLine
  If dict.Exists(fName) Then outFile.WriteLine line
Loop
```

Which one to pick depends on file size and system resources. The second and third approach provide better performance, because they avoid repeated disk I/O, but may lead to memory exhaustion when the file is large.